# Could not install package 'Splat 2.0.0'

Tags: xamarin.forms

Trying to install Splat 2.0.0 into Xamarin Forms project results with error:

Could not install package 'Splat 2.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

How to resolve this issue please?

Thanks,
AG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this on the GitHub of your tool:

> Please use Splat 1.6.2 when targeting PCL projects. v2.0 and onwards is netstandard only. There will be no updates to the 1.6.x series so if you need to patch the release then please fork and maintain your own copy/build from source.

It seems they stopped supporting PCL. So as a solution I suggest using Splat 1.6.2 as that seems to support ¨PCL. Good luck